# document.getElementById is not working for a form

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

I have some code like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id = "inputs" style="width:300px;">   
    <form id = "changePwForm" name = "changePwForm" method = "POST" action = "me.php">
        <input type = "password" id = "currentPw" name = "currentPw" class="loginBlank" style = "width:300px;margin-top:0px;" placeholder="Current Password"/>
        <input type = "password" id = "newPw" name = "newPw" class="loginBlank" style = "width:300px;margin-top:10px;" placeholder="New password"/>
        <input type = "password" id = "newPwCheck" name = "newPwCheck" class="loginBlank" style = "width:300px;margin-top:10px;" placeholder="Retype new password"/>
        <input type = "button" id = "submitBtn" onclick = "checkChangeForm()" class = "loginBlank" value = "Confirm" style = "width:300px;margin-top:10px;font-size:16px;" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function checkChangeForm() {

    var current = document.getElementById("currentPw").value;
    var newPw = document.getElementById("newPw").value;
    var newPwCheck = document.getElementById("newPwCheck").value;
    if (current != "" && newPw != "" && newPwCheck != "") {
        if (newPw == newPwCheck) {
            if (newPw.length >= 8) {
                alert("OK");

                document.getElementById("changePwForm").submit();
            } else {
                alert("Passwords must be longer than 8 characters.");
                document.getElementById("currentPw").value = "";
                document.getElementById("newPw").value = "";
                document.getElementById("newPwCheck").value = "";
                document.getElementById("newPw").focus();
            }
        } else {
            alert("The password does not match!");
            document.getElementById("newPw").value = "";
            document.getElementById("newPwCheck").value = "";
            document.getElementById("newPw").focus();
        }
    } else {
        alert("No password entered");
        document.getElementById("currentPw").value = "";
        document.getElementById("newPw").value = "";
        document.getElementById("newPwCheck").value = "";
        document.getElementById("currentPw").focus();
    }
}
```

Supposing that by the time the button is pressed, the form would have been loaded, and when the variable is created by `document.getElementById("changePwForm")` again, it should be existing. However, it returned **NULL**. Why? What is wrong here?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fL0z59o3/#&togetherjs=FAKVrL1jG3

Comment: Is every getElementById returning null?  Are you positive that the script is waiting for the DOM to load before executing?  My guess is that the script is running before the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Please produce a fiddle

Comment: Which is returning null? document.getElementById("currentPw").value or document.getElementById("currentPw") ?

Comment: But why is the code executed before the button is pressed? I mean like I called the function only on "onclick" and by that time everything should have been loaded.

Comment: Check the console if there are any error. I just tried your code. its working fine for me,  i have just added <script type="text/javascript"> above and your function checkChangeForm() and </script> at the end.

Comment: me.php:101 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null

Comment: try this one. https://jsfiddle.net/fL0z59o3/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the problem... I nested the `<form>` element in another `<form>` element... Removing the outer one made it work.

Answer (score 2):

> Inline-events expect function to be in `global-scope`, not under the scope of `window.onload`

If you want to go on with `window.onload`, bind event using `addEventListener` or `Element.onEVENT_NAME`

```
document.getElementById('submitBtn').addEventListener('click',checkChangeForm);
```

```js
document.getElementById('submitBtn').addEventListener('click',checkChangeForm);
function checkChangeForm() {
  var current = document.getElementById("currentPw").value;
  var newPw = document.getElementById("newPw").value;
  var newPwCheck = document.getElementById("newPwCheck").value;
  if (current != "" && newPw != "" && newPwCheck != "") {
    if (newPw == newPwCheck) {
      if (newPw.length >= 8) {
        alert("OK");

        document.getElementById("changePwForm").submit();
      } else {
        alert("Passwords must be longer than 8 characters.");
        document.getElementById("currentPw").value = "";
        document.getElementById("newPw").value = "";
        document.getElementById("newPwCheck").value = "";
        document.getElementById("newPw").focus();
      }
    } else {
      alert("The password does not match!");
      document.getElementById("newPw").value = "";
      document.getElementById("newPwCheck").value = "";
      document.getElementById("newPw").focus();
    }
  } else {
    alert("No password entered");
    document.getElementById("currentPw").value = "";
    document.getElementById("newPw").value = "";
    document.getElementById("newPwCheck").value = "";
    document.getElementById("currentPw").focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="inputs" style="width:300px;">
  <form id="changePwForm" name="changePwForm" method="POST" action="me.php">
    <input type="password" id="currentPw" name="currentPw" class="loginBlank" style="width:300px;margin-top:0px;" placeholder="Current Password" />
    <input type="password" id="newPw" name="newPw" class="loginBlank" style="width:300px;margin-top:10px;" placeholder="New password" />
    <input type="password" id="newPwCheck" name="newPwCheck" class="loginBlank" style="width:300px;margin-top:10px;" placeholder="Retype new password" />
    <input type="button" id="submitBtn" class="loginBlank" value="Confirm" style="width:300px;margin-top:10px;font-size:16px;" />
  </form>
</div>
```

**Without `window.onload`**

```js
function checkChangeForm() {
  var current = document.getElementById("currentPw").value;
  var newPw = document.getElementById("newPw").value;
  var newPwCheck = document.getElementById("newPwCheck").value;
  if (current != "" && newPw != "" && newPwCheck != "") {
    if (newPw == newPwCheck) {
      if (newPw.length >= 8) {
        alert("OK");

        document.getElementById("changePwForm").submit();
      } else {
        alert("Passwords must be longer than 8 characters.");
        document.getElementById("currentPw").value = "";
        document.getElementById("newPw").value = "";
        document.getElementById("newPwCheck").value = "";
        document.getElementById("newPw").focus();
      }
    } else {
      alert("The password does not match!");
      document.getElementById("newPw").value = "";
      document.getElementById("newPwCheck").value = "";
      document.getElementById("newPw").focus();
    }
  } else {
    alert("No password entered");
    document.getElementById("currentPw").value = "";
    document.getElementById("newPw").value = "";
    document.getElementById("newPwCheck").value = "";
    document.getElementById("currentPw").focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="inputs" style="width:300px;">
  <form id="changePwForm" name="changePwForm" method="POST" action="me.php">
    <input type="password" id="currentPw" name="currentPw" class="loginBlank" style="width:300px;margin-top:0px;" placeholder="Current Password" />
    <input type="password" id="newPw" name="newPw" class="loginBlank" style="width:300px;margin-top:10px;" placeholder="New password" />
    <input type="password" id="newPwCheck" name="newPwCheck" class="loginBlank" style="width:300px;margin-top:10px;" placeholder="Retype new password" />
    <input type="button" id="submitBtn" onclick="checkChangeForm()" class="loginBlank" value="Confirm" style="width:300px;margin-top:10px;font-size:16px;" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not working even without the `window.onload` part.

Comment: @NguyenHChan – I have provided both the solutions..Click on __Run code snippet__ and test!

Comment: Sorry but what was the change made?

Comment: @NguyenHChan— With `window.onload`, use `addEventListener` and with `onclick`, keep function in global scope..

Comment: Like adding this?
`window.onload = function() {
 document.getElementById('submitBtn').addEventListener('click',checkChangeForm);
}`
but still not working...

Comment: @NguyenHChan I have provided both the solutions in my answer.. Let me know if this fails...

Answer (score 0):

include your script just near the end of the body tag, and see if it works.

Comment: I am sorry, if I didn't make myself clear. I asked for a screenshot of your code or some link to view it.

Answer (score -1):

Please move your script just near the end of the body tag

```
<body>
<div id = "inputs" style="width:300px;">   
    <form id = "changePwForm" name = "changePwForm" method = "POST" action = "me.php">
    ........
    </form>
    <script>
    function checkChangeForm() {
    .....
    }
    </script>
</div>
</body>
```